# How do I output the numbers which the variable is divisable with?

Tags: c++, variables

Sorry, I am in trouble with my e-Course homework. 
I was asked to write a program which determines whether the user's input number is prime number and then says its prime or it gives out the numbers the input is divisable with. 
Which kind of syntax should I use to make it happen?
For example:"6 is divisable with 6;3;2;1" 
This is my code so far:

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<conio.h>  
   using namespace std;
   int main()  
   {
   int P,count=0;
   cout<<"Enter a number:\n"; /*Asks for user input*/
   cin>>P;                    /* User input P*/
   for(int a=1;a<=P;a++)
   {
   if(P%a==0)
   {
   count++;
   }
   if(count==2)
         {
        cout<<"Prime number.\n";  /* Provided option when the number is prime number*/
         }
       else
        {
          cout<<" Not prime number \n"; /* This is where I am supposed to provide the               numbers input is divisible with*/
        }
   getch();
   } 
   }
```

Comment: Before banging out code it is a good idea to sketch the algorithm in simple steps - like a recipe. (add flour, check its cooked every minute). So perhaps you code supply pseudo code (fancy name in computing for recipe). By the time you have done that you will probably found what should be wrote. BTW - Leaving assignments to the last minute leads to problems as you feel the urge to bang away with the keyboard. We have all done that - but at least you are honest.

Comment: You either need to keep track of which divisors are found by storing them in a vector, or print them out as you find them. The latter option is probably easiest if you haven't covered vectors yet. Firstly you don't need to worry about dividing by 1 or P, so you can remove them from your loop. Next you need a way to flag whether you've found any divisors before. If you haven't, then you can print 'Not prime number' before you start printing the divisors as you find them (and set your flag to true for the next iteration). If you get to the end of the loop and your flag is still false, you can th

Comment: Hmm, actually did my programs in the last weekend, and started with trying to sketch them out, took my time.Worked a bit every evening how to debug them and now it seems like the last questions/errors seem to be beyond me right now.I wish I had posted these questions yesterday but I thought I can figure them out and learn in the process, sadly I did learn a bit but not enough to finish the tasks.

Comment: @user210567 - Forget the computer in the first instance. How would you train a money and write that on paper. They code to that.

Comment: Thanks,to be honest all I needed was the word divisor.Silly by me, I know, but there is no mention of it in the course materials to help me reach this very much needed command.

Comment: @Ed I actually sketch them out in the head. I am a bit of a weirdo, because I didn't acquire sense of logic through math but through the mixture of history,biology and physics instead.So I try to put things into perspective in my head before I start laying it down.Nonetheless, thanks for the input :)

Comment: Just write it down. It usually helps. It focuses your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what's wrong, but your program prints something like

```
Enter a number:
6
 Not prime number 
Prime number.
 Not prime number 
 Not prime number 
 Not prime number 
 Not prime number
```

Also, `<conio.h>` is not standard C++. I suggest you write something like this (note the use of `std::vector` to accumulate the divisors):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    if (n == 0) {
        "Not a prime; 0 is divisible by all integers";
        return 0;
    }

    std::vector<int> divisors;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            divisors.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    if (divisors.size() > 2) {
        std::cout << "Not a prime; divisors:" << std::endl;
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = divisors.begin(); it != divisors.end(); it++) {
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Prime" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,H2CO3. I use <conio.h> because I am very fond of the getch(); to check the output.If I am not mistaken, the getch(); was probably the most compatible command with the operation systems aswell?

Comment: @user2105267 If you run it from a terminal, you don't need any of that non-standard nonsense ;-)

Comment: @user2105267 (also, to support myself in the defense of a complete answer: you seem to be in the serious need to learn nice coding style. I showed you a sample of that.)

Comment: @user2105267, Also, if you're interested, there are some good articles on writing better prime number programs. This loops through `[1, n]` and checks each one. A common first step is to reduce that to `[2, floor(sqrt(n))]`. There's much more you can do beyond that.